# Deleting all blobs in a directory with Azure.Storage.Blobs

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am refactor my code to Azure.Storage.Blobs as windowsAzure.Storage is getting depricated. However I have not found anyways to delete a "directoty". In the old library you could do something like:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Config.StorageConnStr);
CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(StorageConnection);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(ExportContainerName);
CloudBlobDirectory folder = container.GetDirectoryReference(jobid.ToLower());
var blobs = folder.ListBlobs();

foreach (var blob in blobs)
{
    ((CloudBlob)blob).DeleteIfExists();
}
```

But I cannot see any similar code with the new package. Any pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [GetBlobsByHierarchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.getblobsbyhierarchy?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_BlobContainerClient_GetBlobsByHierarchy_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobTraits_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobStates_System_String_System_String_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) method to [list blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list?tabs=dotnet#use-a-hierarchical-listing) in your directory, and then delete them.

Please refer to my code:

```
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            var resultSegment = containerClient.GetBlobsByHierarchy(BlobTraits.None, BlobStates.None, "/", "frankfolder/").AsPages(default, 100);
            
            foreach (Azure.Page<BlobHierarchyItem> blobPage in resultSegment)
            {
                foreach (BlobHierarchyItem blobhierarchyItem in blobPage.Values)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Blob name: {0}", blobhierarchyItem.Blob.Name);
                    containerClient.DeleteBlob(blobhierarchyItem.Blob.Name);
                }
            }
```

Comment: It's very unfortunately there isn't support for batch deleting by meta tag, pseudo dir or regex patterns. Especially if you are doing this from a function, they charge you for the compute cycles. Ugh

Comment: @Justin answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70778809/how-to-retrieve-blobs-within-a-blob-directory-path-using-the-azure-storage-blobs may help with filterning