# How to retrieve blobs within a blob directory path using the Azure.Storage.Blobs BlobClient?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, blobstorage

I'm not seeing any examples online on how to get all the blobs located inside a certain directory within a `BlobContainerClient`.

Previously, I was using the `Microsoft.Azure.Storage` packages, but those have since been deprecated. My old code that was scanning a directory for all blobs was:

```
public async Task<void> ListAllBlobs(string path)
{
    var myContainer = await GetCloudBlobClientAsync();
    var directory = myContainer.GetDirectoryReference(path);
    var blobs = await directory.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(true, BlobListingDetails.None, 
        blobSettings.MaxResult, null, null, null);
    var results = blobs.Results;

    foreach(CloudBlockBlob b in results)
    {
        // non-relevant code
    }
}

private async Task<CloudBlobContainer> GetCloudBlobClientAsync()
{
    var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(azureBlobStorageConnectionString);
    var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(blobStorageSettings.ContainerName);

    if (!await container.ExistsAsync())
    {
        await container.CreateAsync();
    }

    return container;
}
```

Essentially, I'm moving the above code from `Microsoft.Azure.Storage` over to `Azure.Storage.Blobs`.

If I were to recreate the `ListAllBlobs(string path)` function to use `Azure.Storage.Blobs`, I'm confused on how to setup a container and then access an inner container based on a path that's passed in - then cycle through the blobs that exist within that container. Can anyone help?

Here's what I have so far:

```
public async Task<void> ListAllBlobs(string path)
{
    var myContainer = await GetCloudBlobClientAsync();
    var directory = myContainer.GetBlobClient(path);

    // This doesn't work because I can't do 'GetBlobs' on the Client, only on the container.
    foreach(BlobItem blob in directory.GetBlobs(Blobtraits.None, BlobStates.None, string.Empty))
    {
        // more non-relevant code
    }
}
```

To clarify, in the above code, it doesn't like that I'm calling `GetBlobs` on a Client, rather than on the Container, but I can't pass in a path to the container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were almost there. You would still use [`BlobContainerClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient?view=azure-dotnet) and call [`GetBlobsAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.getblobsasync?view=azure-dotnet) method on that. What you missed is that you will need to set the `prefix` parameter's value as the `path`.

So your code would be something like:

```
var myContainer = await GetCloudBlobClientAsync();
var blobsListingResult = await myContainer.GetBlobsAsync(prefix=path);
```

**UPDATE**

Please try the following code:

```
var myContainer = await GetCloudBlobClientAsync();
await foreach (BlobItem blob in myContainer.GetBlobsAsync(BlobTraits.None, BlobStates.None, path))
{
  names.Add(blob.Name);
}
```

Comment: The only issue now is when I do `GetBlobsAsync(prefix=path)`, the error is "The name 'prefix' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: If I do `GetBlobsAsync(BlobTraits.None, BlobStates.None, path)`, the error is "'AsyncPageable<BlobItem>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'..."

Comment: Updated my answer with modified code. Please give that a try.

Comment: You're the bomb, this was exactly what I was missing, thanks!

Comment: Out of curiousity, within that `foreach` loop you're doing above, how would you go about a Delete Blob. The the deprecated SDK v11, it was simple: `await blob.DeleteAsync()`,

Comment: Using the blob name and the container client you will need to create an instance of `BlobClient` using `GetBlobClient` method and then you would call `DeleteAsync` method on that object.

Answer (score 6):

Try this ...

```
static async Task GetBlobs()
{
    string connectionString = "<connection_string>";
    string containerName = "<container_name>";

    var blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName);

    var blobs = blobContainerClient.GetBlobs(Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobTraits.All, Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobStates.All,
        "YourPrefix");

    foreach (var blob in blobs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(blob.Name); 
    }
}
```

... that worked for me.

[image: Example]

Comment: Sadly, this solution does not work. The error on directory.GetBlobs is "'BlobClient' does not contain a definition for 'GetBlobs' and no accessible extension method 'GetBlobs' accepting a first argument of type 'BlobClient' could be found."

Comment: In my haste to fix my answer, I realised I omitted a fairly important line of code, which, may or may not help you get with your question.  The object I am instantiating (`BlobContainerClient`) is a little different to the way you're doing it.  Does that help?

Comment: Thank you this was great help for the approach you took!